# One-Way Communication with iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

On my site, I have an `iframe` that displays content which is at least in part user-generated, but also needs to have scripts act upon it.  Right now I communicate with the frame by targeting its `contentWindow` property, which is nice since the actual script runs outside (in a technical sense) of the frame itself.

**However**, what I'd really like to do is shut down all scripts inside of the frame entirely, without stopping scripts that originate on my parent frame from acting on the frame's window.

I tried using the `sandbox` property in various forms, but it seems to be an all or nothing deal.  I also tried sanitization, but part of the user-generated content is fully-formed HTML, which is at best enormously difficult to clean.

***How can I stop all scripts in an iFrame (same-domain) while still giving the top frame scripting access?***